# Sending Mail from Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am trying to send an email from google app engine using the python 2.7 library but I keep getting Unauthorized sender in the logs.  I have tried my gmail account I created the application with as the sender, I registered another gmail address as a developer and tried that but still get Unauthorized sender.  I am not sure if it matters but I do have a domain name registered to this application.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
message = mail.EmailMessage()
        message.sender = "ron.....@gmail.com"
        message.subject = "Inquiry"
        message.to = "ron.....@gmail.com"
        message.body = "Please work"
        message.send()
```

I have looked at other articles to no avail.

[Google Appengine sending emails: [Error] unauthorized sender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621019/google-appengine-sending-emails-error-unauthorized-sender)

[InvalidSenderError: Unauthorized sender (Google App Engine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217972/invalidsendererror-unauthorized-sender-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 2):

```
from google.appengine.api import mail

mail.send_mail(sender="stackoverflow.com Hossam <Hossam@stackoverflow.com>",
              to="rsnyder <rsnyder@stackoverflow.com>",
              subject="How to send an e-mail using google app engine",
              body="""
Dear rsnyder:

This example shows how to send an e-mail using google app engine

Please let me know if this is what you want.

Best regards,
""")
```

EDIT:

Note that `sender` must be an `administrator` of the application, so in case that you are not and `administrator`, follow these steps from the post [google app engine: how to add adminstrator account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020317/google-app-engine-how-to-add-adminstrator-account)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply Hossam but I still get Unauthorized sender (I did replace the sender address with my admin email address in your example).

Comment: That's probably because the app sends e-mails on behalf of the `administrators` which the sender is not. As for, you need to add `administrators` to the application using the `Administration Console`

Comment: I tried that and even tried adding another admin and developer and those email addresses also get Unauthorized sender.  I have read the documentation and other stackover flow articles and not had any luck.

Comment: The code below is tested and works fine, and if you have applied what was said here at this post you pointed (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621019/google-appengine-sending-emails-error-unauthorized-sender) then i can't help you no longer as i don't know what else could it be the problem. so please re-check again carefully on all of it and lemme know.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  It was the wrong version of the code.  I switched to a version 2 and didn't realize I had to activate it.